# 220V AC to 12V DC transformerless and main isolated converter?

Tags: converter, ac-dc

I am trying to build a 220/12V AC/DC max 100mA converter without transformer. I tried so much and burned some circuits. at the end I decide to write here. I searched but couldn't find and answered question here. Could you please help me to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why no transformer, and why not just buy one?

Comment: What circuit did you use and how do you believe it is isolated without a transformer?

Comment: @geometrikal I tried to build my own to use it in my project.

Comment: @Andyaka I used this http://img.bhs4.com/18/7/1877240dea6bcc501fcf5ebf11406d5d610ba3a7_large.jpg

Comment: @muratimurtas: How is that isolated?

Comment: Just buy one off the shelf for safety reasons. Or just buy a USB charger and provide power to your device using the 5V output.

Comment: @geometrikal You mean there is no way to build it ?

Comment: @Rev1.0 The builder is saying that. ( the site that I searched http://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/77929-make-a-transformerless-power-supply/)

Comment: @muratimurtas: You should re-read the article. They initially claimed it has "isolation", but even then with limitations. They supplemented: "A reader advised us that information regarding the final circuit was outdated and potentially dangerous. This information has since been updated with a disappointing twist to the initial positive outcome the author experienced. Note, that this article is intended for informational purposes only, and intended for experienced electricians."

Comment: ...further: "Here, if the phase is connected to the capacitor C1, the mains AC becomes isolated and it's quite safe to touch the output of the circuit, but if the phase is accidentally connected to the other input terminal, the whole circuit hangs at LETHAL MAINS POTENTIAL, a big and a dangerous drawback."

Comment: @Rev1.0 thank you very much I missed that information I just trust the title :(

Comment: @Rev1.0 I read whole article and I will not use it.

Comment: Without isolation provided by a transformer it is not isolated

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is VERY DANGEROUS, mainly because you do not know enough to know what the risks are.

Good, safe, reliable, certified safe power supplies are cheap and plentiful and available in "wall wart" and "power brick" styles very cheaply requiring only a DC jack on your device. If it is just a home project you can probably find an old power supply around the house you can use.

If you MUST build a mains power supply into your device there are MANY things you must know & take account of in the design & layout & manufacture of the device. But these cannot be relevant because you would be INSANE to produce & sell such a thing without knowing a LOT more than you do now & having a professional certify the electrical safety before you were able to sell it to anyone without a high risk of someone being injured or killed - and if you are in a country where such a thing is likely, you will also be sued for damages by the injured party & probably taken to court by the authorities for selling an unsafe product.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a Capacitive Power Supply: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf

However, such supplies are not isolated. The transformer is the only real form of isolation you can get, unless you want something silly like a mains powered light shining on a solar panel. If you want to build a capacitive powers supply I suggest you get an isolated mains transformer to protect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SR086 or SR087.
these are excellent transformerless IC for generating the needed voltage with additional 3.3V and 5V regulated voltage to drive the Controller IC's from the mains respectively. 
The mains can be from 90V to 270V AC. check out the below datasheet. make sure you use the proper rating of the components. Its available at Microchip if you want in bulk.
**Galvanic isolation is not provided. make sure you add a circuit for shock prevention from the user.** If you are using it in a concealed container and not available for the user to touch directly then you can go ahead and use it. has around 55% conversion efficiency.

drawbacks : it won't work if you connect transformer and wont work from the inverter with modified sine wave O/p.

http://kazus.ru/nuke/users_files/03032008/7568180.pdf

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is QUITE DANGEROUS.

Are you aware that that kind of systems is **not providing any insulation** between mains and output and so what you name 0V or +12V could possibly be at full 230 V mains potential?

Please clarify what are you about to feed by this circuit. Thx

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I asked here because if I try to do that yes you are right it will be dangerous.However if someone who is expert can help me to achieve that without danger. I did not know about insulation. I will feed a 555 timer circuit which I asked before in another question you can check it.